# Rendering a list of images with corresponding links

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, pug

I am sending back a list of links and a list of links for the images.

Each image has a corresponding link that is the page it should go to when the image is clicked.

This is the current code I have in my jade file.

webcomic is the list of links and cells is the list of links for the images I am rendering.

```
- for comic, cell in webcomic, cells
    li
        p
            | <a href="#{comic}"><img align="left" src="#{cell}" alt="" border="0" width="80" height="60" /></a>
```

However, at the moment it does not seem to even be taking in the src="#{cell}" field for the images.

I want to display each #{cell} with a #{comic}.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your underlying data structure?

Comment: cells and webcomic are both arrays from a typescript file.

Comment: I think that "- for comic, cell in webcomic, cells" this may not be the correct syntax but I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: Might be useful to take a look at [iteration](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/).
Didn't use jade like that in a long time, so I can't test my ideas right now - would help if you could provide an example

Comment: is there a way to iterate over two lists in jade?

Comment: Not sure, but it is probably a better idea to rework your data structure anyway.
Since the link and the image source are so tightly coupled why not just create a object array like `[{ link: 'link', source: 'source' }]` and iterate over that

Comment: Hmmm, right now in the typescript file I am sending back `{ "webcomic": comicIDLinks, "cells": comicCellIDs }` . What sort of example would be helpful?

Comment: I just need something I can run and do tests on (not sure if jsfiddle/plunkr can handle jade stuff). You could also give me a link to a git repository.
Try returning `{ entries: [{link: comicIdLink1, imageSource: commicCellId1}, {link: comicIdLink2, ...}, ...] }` instead. Then you can loop over one object and have access to both values together.